# Conditionally Compile Tests with MakeFile

Tags: c, makefile

I'm working on a project right now in C where I have different modules that I'm implementing and I want to be able to test the module implementations separately by having an individual test file for each module where I define and run my tests for that module. I have each test file have its own main function and am trying to overcome the multiple main function error when compiling. I've looked into it an it seems the solution is to conditionally compile the main functions and then have a common test runner file where I call those. So far I've used ifdef on the test file's main functions like so

```
   //util_test.c 
   #ifdef UTIL_TEST_MAIN
    int main(){
        printf("bits2bytes tests:\n");
        test_bits2bytes();
        //.. rest of my test functions
        return 0;
    }
    #endif
```

I've also done the same for a freelist test files main function then in my test_runner.c file I have

```
extern int util_test_main(void);
extern int test_freelist_main(void);
int main() {
    util_test_main();
    test_freelist_main();
    return 0;
}
```

my file structure is as follows

```
.
├── balloc.c
├── balloc.h
├── bbm.c
├── bbm.h
├── bm.c
├── bm.h
├── freelist.c
├── freelist.h
├── GNUmakefile
├── Tests
│   ├── freelist_test.c
│   ├── freelist_test.h
│   ├── test_macro.h
│   ├── test_runner.c
│   ├── util_test.c
│   └── util_test.h
├── utils.c
├── utils.h
└── wrapper.c
```

I'm attempting to create a Makefile that will compile and run my tests with the option to run all the tests or to select individual tests and am having issues with it not finding a target for the test c files. I'm very new to creating MakeFiles so I've been using Chat on a repl.it Makefile to try  and do this but am having little success. Here is the current Makefile

```
CC = gcc
override CFLAGS += -g -Wno-everything -pthread -lm

SRCS = $(shell find . -name '.ccls-cache' -type d -prune -o -type f -name '*.c' -print)
HEADERS = $(shell find . -name '.ccls-cache' -type d -prune -o -type f -name '*.h' -print)

# List of test files
TESTS = util_test freelist_test

.PHONY: all clean test $(TESTS)

all: main

main: $(SRCS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCS) -o "$@"

main-debug: $(SRCS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -O0 $(SRCS) -o "$@"

$(TESTS): % : %.c test_runner.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< test_runner.c $(SRCS) -o $@
    ./$@

test: $(TESTS)

valgrind: main
    valgrind --leak-check=full ./main

clean:
    rm -f main main-debug $(TESTS)
```

Comment: "*it seems the solution is to conditionally compile the main functions*" -- that's **one** solution that probably can be made to work.  But I'm not following why it's necessary.  It seems more natural to decide either to give each test its own `main()` (that is, one belonging to the test itself), or to choose or build a test framework that supplies its own `main()` for use by all the tests.  Either way, I'm not seeing why multiple definitions of `main()` would need to be a problem to work around, whether via conditional compilation or otherwise.

Comment: well right now each test has its own `main()` but when I try to run `make`  using my old Makefile when I only had one test with a `main()` I get a compilation error stating there are multiple definitions of main.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the issue. You *choose one*: either the framework provides the `main()` function for each test, or each test provides its own.  That way, no executable draws on more than one source file providing a `main()`.  If you want to share code among different tests, then the shared functions go into one or more separate source files that do not provide a `main()` -- these do not themselves correspond to tests.

Comment: Note also that in this model, none of the tests can rely on the source file providing the main application's `main()`.

Comment: What I do is compile my library `.c` files to `.o` (before building them into a library), and I compile test programs from the same `.c` files with the extra flag `-DTEST`.  The files themselves contain `#ifdef TEST` / `int main(void)` / `{ … }` / `#endif` at the end (along with whatever other infrastructure is needed to test the code).  The test programs are compiled by a rule that converts a `.c` file into a program (`.c:` in the old `make` notation); the object files are compiled by a normal rule (`.c.o:`).  There are rules in the makefile to create all the test programs, and clean them up.

Comment: You are a pretty long way from a working solution here.  But before we can help you get there, you have to make a decision.  _EITHER_ you want to have one individual test program for each test (that is, have a program `util_test` and another program `freelist_test`, that you invoke individually), _OR_ you want a single program like `test_runner` that you invoke and it runs all the tests together.  _OR_ you want both individual test programs AND a single program (which seems like overkill to me, but could be done).  Once you explain what you want we can help you achieve it.